# How can I get the link of all the posts in the Instagram profile with Selenium?

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to get the links of all the posts in an instagram profile.
How can I get to the href="/p/CX067tNhZ8i/" in the photo.

What I'm trying to do is find the href= blabla of all posts.

All your posts are in class="v1Nh3 kIKUG _bz0w".

I tried to get the hraf= blabla value from this class with the get_attribute command, but it didn't work.

Thank you for your help.

```
browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/lightning.mcqueen34/")

links = []
elements = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/section/main/div/div[4]/article/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]')
for i in elements:
    links.append(i.get_attribute('href'))
```

I thought this would work but the elements value is not a list . It gave an error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change XPath first to get the DIV class or ID after trying this `//a[@href]` Xpath to get all HREF.

Comment: ıt's give me only the follower count of this account.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:`elements = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')`

Below answer will not work in all cases, dependant on how the DOM of the page is loaded.

Replace this line:

`elements = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/section/main/div/div[4]/article/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]')`

With:

`elements = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href]")`

This will let you retreive all links with a href from the page.

Comment: ıt's give me only the follower count of this account. –